# complete code that implement go to definition

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-code

I am using vs code for code editor. One feature I really like is "go to definition". However, my code is mixed with c++ and matlab source code. When I open  c++ code, I can use the feature to jump to a new location in different file. However, for matlab code I could not do it. In gvim, I can use gf command to jump to files with suffixes add. In source insight, I can add simple definition for matlab function. But in vs I can not do it. I want to create my own go to definition for matlab function. But the vs code is too complicated (compare with gvim and source insight) to create such feature for a new language.

Could someone pointed me a location that I can get a complete implementation of this feature, so I can modify the code to fit for matlab function? To create by myself without such code is really out of my capability. I googled around and do find some information about this. But they are not complete and hard to understand for me.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: This question is for VS code (visual-studio-code).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking (I feel like an example here would be worth 1000 words), and possibly off topic because you're asking us to recommend an off-site resource.